# Several relationships between two tables- is it correct or not?

Tags: t-sql, database-design, data-modeling, rdbms

These day I work with a database that have this style of relationship then I've been very confused with it. This database is in a very large web app & have worked well for 10 years then I wonder whether this design is good in someway? or in which situations I should implement it?
Welcome any idea!
[image: many relation between 2 tables]

Comment: Without knowing the *semantics* of the tables and the related columns, it is impossible to know.

Comment: It is perhaps "good" if it lets you model the data you need to model.... so.... does it? text-book examples would be things like holding a delivery address, invoice address, originating address etc against an order (i.e. 3 foreign keys to an Address table)

Comment: @LongTTH that's very weird :\ can you give us some logic from those two tables please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in my opinion. You can have, for example, in a *personal_data* table a *place_of_birth* field and a *place_of_living* field both referring to a *cities* table. By the way you should post a more meaningful example to have a more precise answer.